# Error: credentials argument needs to implement signRequest method

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I got a question -- I am trying to reuse the response from the ms-rest-nodeauth library. This way everytime I use my tool, I only need to authenticate if the authentication context is not valid.. Whenever I try to use the returned response I get this error

```
Error: credentials argument needs to implement signRequest method
```

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If not already done then I believe that you would have to double check the code by leveraging the samples provided in [this](https://github.com/Azure/ms-rest-nodeauth) repo. If those samples are not helpful to resolve your error then raising an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/ms-rest-nodeauth/issues) / [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues) would help you with better response from the repository contributors, etc.

Other references:

- [ms-rest-nodeauth (azure-sdk-for-js) : Error: credentials argument needs to implement signRequest method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856407/ms-rest-nodeauth-azure-sdk-for-js-error-credentials-argument-needs-to-imple)
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/3936

Comment: I've already reached out to the maintainers of the project.

The documentation is not clear on reuse of authentication context .. I assumed I can use the credentials response to authenticate again but I get the above mentioned error.